# CSS for email client inbox

Tags: html, css, list

I am creating an email client, I want the inbox to resemble that of Mac Mail[image: Mac Mail Inbox]

I am pulling the emails themselves from a database using ajax (outputting to XML) and then looping through the entries and pulling the relevant elements.

What I have never been confident with is the css. I want to create the elements using `<ul>` and `<li>`. My understanding is that I will need to nest these. For example:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <ul>
        <li class="from">Mike @ Hotmail</li>
        <li class="subject">Hello</li>
        <li class="date">13/01/2013</li>
        <li class="preview">Lorem Ipsum....</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul>
        <li class="from">Jame @ Gmail</li>
        <li class="subject">Out Of Office</li>
        <li class="date">12/01/2013</li>
        <li class="preview">Lorem Ipsum....</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
.from {

}

.subject {

}

.date {

}

.preview {

}
```

What I don't know is whether I need to reference the `<ul>` and `<li>` items within the CSS, does that make a difference? Also, what are the things that I need to create this look?

PLEASE DO NOT ANSWER THIS. I THINK I HAVE WORKED IT OUT. WHEN I AM HAPPY WITH THE OUTCOME I WILL POST HERE FOR OTHERS TO WORK FROM IN THE FUTURE...

Ok, I give up, this is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.inboxPanel {
    width: 420px;
}

ul.inbox {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.message {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
}

.from {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.subject {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.date {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

.preview {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="inboxPanel">
    <ul class="inbox">
        <li>
            <ul class="message">
                <li class="from">Mike @ Hotmail</li>

                <li class="subject">Hello</li>

                <li class="date">13/01/2013</li>

                <li class="preview">Lorem Ipsum....</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <ul class="message">
                <li class="from">Jame @ Gmail</li>

                <li class="subject">Out Of Office</li>

                <li class="date">12/01/2013</li>

                <li class="preview">Lorem Ipsum....</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <ul class="message">
                <li class="from">Mike @ Hotmail</li>

                <li class="subject">Hello</li>

                <li class="date">13/01/2013</li>

                <li class="preview">Lorem Ipsum....</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <ul class="message">
                <li class="from">Jame @ Gmail</li>

                <li class="subject">Out Of Office</li>

                <li class="date">12/01/2013</li>

                <li class="preview">Lorem Ipsum....</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: screen shot of design so far]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, first of all

```
<ul>
    <li class="from">Mike @ Hotmail</li>
    <li class="subject">Hello</li>
    <li class="date">13/01/2013</li>
    <li class="preview">Lorem Ipsum....</li>
</ul>
```

makes no sense semantically. From, subject, date and preview are not a list. Your email messages ARE a list, but the email components are not.

What you should do is something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="from"></span>
        <span class="date"></span>
        <p class="subject></p>
        <p class="preview"></p>
    </li>
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
li { overflow: hidden; }
li span.from { float: left; font-weight: bold; }
li span.date { float: right; }
li p.subject { clear: both; font-weight: bold; }
li p.preview { color: #ccc; }
```

This is just rough styling to make the layout look the way you want. You'll have to tweak it for proper padding, colors, etc.